AuthMiddleware Deprecated: How to Fix Issues with clerkMiddleware?
With the deprecation of authMiddleware, I’m looking for guidance on how to update my code. My previous implementation was structured like this:The code
What would be the recommended approach to achieve the same functionality with the updated tools or methods provided by Clerk? Any examples or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
I tried going through the documentation. But being a beginner I couldn't get much out of it. Then I tried some alternatives using the help of chatGPT. Those too were unsuccessful.
The code is here:
import { authMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs'

export default authMiddleware({
    publicRoutes: "/site","/apit/"
})

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/((?!. +\\. [\\w] +$ |_next).*)', '/',
        '/(api|trpc) (.*)'
    ],
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
